# Why doesn't Google font show up in PDF generated by html-pdf-node on a server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm failing to use a Google font in a PDF rendered on the server, using html-pdf-node. When I run it on my local machine, it works fine.

```js
Res.render("folder/file_name", {data_res:populated_data}, async(err, html) => {
    var html_to_pdf = require('html-pdf-node');
    let file = { content:html}
    var options = {format:'A4'};
    let pdfBuffer = await html_to_pdf.generatePdf(file, options);
    let fileName = `generated_pdf.pdf`;
    const { Buffer } = require('buffer');
    const pdfData = pdfBuffer; // assume pdfData is a buffer containing the PDF file data
    Res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${fileName}`);
    Res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    Res.send(Buffer.from(pdfData));
});
```